# In OpenCV.fisheye, What is difference between 'calibrate()' and 'undistortimage()' functions?

Tags: python, opencv, distortion, calibration, fisheye

I read **OpenCV.fisheye** official manual, and I'm confused about the use of `calibrate()` and `undistortImage()` functions.

I know that both are used to fix some distortion in an image but, it looks too similar to me.

The docs I referred to are:

- https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/db/d58/group__calib3d__fisheye.html
- https://hackaday.io/project/12384-autofan-automated-control-of-air-flow/log/41862-correcting-for-lens-distortions

If you know, explain the difference between them, please share it... :)

Comment: Do you mean `undistortImage()` ?

Comment: Oh!! Yes!! I had a serious mistake....
`distortImage()` -> `undistortImage()` is right!
Thank you for your taking a look :)

Answer (score 0):

`calibrate()` returns you your camera's intrinsic parameters / distortion coefficients which then can be passed into `undistortImage()` to correct for the lens warping.